# Reactive Extensions support for WPF in .Net 5.0

Tags: c#, wpf, reactive-programming, system.reactive, .net-5

I am trying to use DispatcherScheduler.Current in an example WPF app, the following line does not resolve the class (static).

Does anyone know why this not resolve?

```
 public partial class App : Application
 {
     public App()
     {
         **var tmp = DispatcherScheduler.Current;**
     }
 }
```

The csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reactive" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The following support issue on GitHub suggest this should work - [here](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/1423)

OS: Mircosoft Windows 10 Pro,
Version: 10.0.19042

Comment: Have you added a using statement? `using System.Reactive.Concurrency;`?

Comment: Already tried adding the namespace, as comment below states, adding ReactiveUI does get it to work but not ideal.

Comment: It worked for me when I created a new WPF application and added the `System.Reactive` library.

Comment: .Net 5.0 app compiling in VS2019?

Comment: Oh, actually 4.7.X.

Comment: :) at least i'm not going mad!

Comment: I updated my answer and it looks like there is an issue on github similar to your issue: https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/1497.

Answer (score 2):

I made a fresh **.NET 5 WPF** project and I saw same issue. Adding nuget `ReactiveUi` solved missing `DispatcherScheduler`, but don't know why `DispatcherScheduler` is not available by referencing just `System.Reactive`.

**Update:**
I tested fresh project, but for **.NET Core 3.1 WPF** and everything is OK. It's issue with **.NET 5**.

**Update 2:**
I found issue on github https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/1497, `DispatcherScheduler` is available for TFM `net5.0-windows10.0.19041`. I also used ILSpy to ensure that `System.Reactive.dll` is different for `.net5.0` and `net5.0-windows10.0.19041`.
Changing `TargetFramework` in `csproj` to:

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.19041</TargetFramework>
```

solves issue.

Comment: Just to add that it also works on .NET 6: 
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041</TargetFramework>